# Using IF statement to create 2 different output files in Python Script tool of ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, parameters

I have a model which needs to only produce 1 final report but is dependent on whether a variable is provided.So there are 2 different flows following on from that selection

Something like this, a policy number can be provided or not, if it is 1 report is generated (output2) if its not(output)

[image]

A python script has been saved as a geoprocessing tasks with the 2 outputs to feed into different chains of the model.

My script within the processing tool is:

```
import arcpy

input_data = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
policynumber = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

if policynumber == '':
    output = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(input_data, 'NEW_SELECTION')

else:
    output2 = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(input_data, 'NEW_SELECTION', "PolicyNumber = '{}'".format(policynumber))


arcpy.SetParameterAsText(2, output)
arcpy.SetParameterAsText(3, output2)
```

I am getting the error that 'output' is not defined.

Is this because I've built the second output into the IF statement?

How can I fix it?

Is there a better/easier way to generate a different report dependent on whether a selection has occurred?

Comment: So, I've completed the full model, with separate workflows dependent on the IF statement. However it only seems to work with a policy number, despite setting that as an optional variable. If I don't enter a policy number, I want it to run on the full input file but it seems to just create a blank output.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you only define one output, depending on the IF. And then you try to use both, regardless.

So maybe use:

```
output = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(input_data, 'NEW_SELECTION')
output2 = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(input_data, 'NEW_SELECTION', "PolicyNumber = '{}'".format(policynumber))

if policynumber == '':
    arcpy.SetParameterAsText(2, output) 
else:
    arcpy.SetParameterAsText(3, output2)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's helped and fixed my problem!

Comment: So, I've completed the full model, with separate workflows dependent on the IF statement. However it only seems to work with a policy number, despite setting that as an optional variable. If I don't enter a policy number, I want it to run on the full input file but it seems to just create a blank output. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: not sure, maybe show me the new code